# what happens when I kill a yarn's node manager

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Suppose there are 10 containers running on this machine(5 is mapreduce tasks, and 5 is spark on yarn executors).

And if I kill the node manager, what happens for these 10 containers process?

Before I restart the node manager ,what should I do first?

Comment: I think you mean what happens when the **ResourceManager** dies. The *NodeManager* is what manages all containers on each slave node.

Comment: I can't answer your question, except in the case of High Availability being configured (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html), in which case nothing happens. I guess you gotta try and see yourself ! However I can make your question even more interesting, by asking, what happens when the node with the ApplicationMaster dies ?

Answer (score 1):

Killing nodemanager will only affect the containers of this particular node. All the running containers will get lost on restart/kill. They will get relaunched once the node comes up or the nodemanager process get start(if application/job still running).
NOTE: Jobs ApplicationMaster should not be running on this slave.

what happens when the node with the ApplicationMaster dies ?
In this case the yarn launchs a new ApplicationMaster on some other node. All the containers relaunched again in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Answering according to hadoop 2.7.x dist: check this article: http://hortonworks.com/blog/resilience-of-yarn-applications-across-nodemanager-restarts/

If you don't have `yarn.nodemanager.recovery.enabled` set to true then you're container will be KILLED (spark or mapreduce or anything else) However you're job will most likely continue to run.

You need to check this property in your env using `hadoop conf | grep yarn.nodemanager.recovery.dir` . If it false which is for me by default then nothing you can do to prevent getting those container killed upon restart imo. However you can try to modify the flag and set other required property for future cases if you want containers to be recovered.

Look at this one too: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/admin_ha_yarn_work_preserving_recovery.html